# How a compiler knows from a header file, that a source file exists somewhere?

Tags: c++, c, include, preprocessor-directive

I just started to learn C/C++, but I'm a bit confused. I often see the `#include` preprocessor directive, with a header file argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h> 
#include "windows.h"
#include <math.h>
```

But sometimes the `.h` is missing:

```
#include <iostream>
```

I already know, that the header file contains the signatures of the functions only, and some preprocessor commands. But when and how does the compiler include the math functions, if I include `math.h`?

If I create a library, then where to put the .c/.cpp/.h files, and how to include them?

Comment: That's a good example why you should not mix C and C++

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Which of these two languages are you learning and which language is your question about?

Comment: (1) Don't aim to learn the non-existent language C/C++. Choose one. I'd recommend C++. (2) Post **real code**. It appears that @wilx fixed your code. That was a service to readers but a disservice to you, because you really need to learn to post real code, so that others won't have to fix things for you, or be mislead by the errors in your posted code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you install the compiler, the standard header and library files are also installed into well-known locations.  For example, on a Linux or Unix system, the standard headers are typically installed under `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include` and the standard libraries are typically installed under `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

When you `#include` the header file, the compiler will look for it in different places depending on whether you use the angle brackets (`#include <stdio.h>`) or quotes (`#include "myfile.h"`).  For example, if you include a header file in angle brackets, `gcc` will search for that header in the following directories:

```
/usr/local/include
libdir/gcc/target/version/include
/usr/target/include
/usr/include
```

If you include a header file with quotes, `gcc` will first search the current working directory, then additional directories as specified by command-line options, and finally the standard include paths above.

Most compilers allow you to specify additional include paths as arguments to compile command, such as

```
gcc -o executable-name -I /additional/include/path source-files
```

> But sometimes the .h is missing:
>
> `#include <iostream>`

This is the C++ convention<sup>1</sup>; C++ standard headers do not have the `.h` extension, I guess to make it *look* more object-oriented than it really is (that is, you can pretend you're importing the class directly, rather than including the text of the file that describes the class).

> I already know, that the header file contains the signatures of the functions only, and some preprocessor commands. But when and how does the compiler include the math functions, if I include math.h?

The implementations of the math functions are typically kept in a separate library (code that's already been compiled and archived into a single binary file); depending on the compiler, the math library may or may not be automatically linked into the executable.  For example, `gcc` does not automatically link in any math library functions, even if you include the `math.h` header file.  You have to explicitly include the math library as part of the build command:

```
gcc -o executable-name command-line-options source-files -lm
```

With `gcc`, the convention is that `-lname` links in a library named `libname.a`<sup>2</sup>.  The standard math library file is named `libm.a`, so `-lm` tells `gcc` to link in the machine code that's contained within `libm.a`.

Like the standard headers, the compiler will search for the standard libraries in well-known locations.  You can specify additional search paths for libraries that aren't part of the standard installation, like so:

```
gcc -o executable-name command-line-options source-files -L /additional/library/path -ladditional-library
```

> If I create a library, then where to put the .c/.cpp/.h files, and how to include them?

You can put the files pretty much anywhere you want; you'll specify where they are as part of the build command.  So, say you're creating a new library named `mylib`.  You create a new directory under your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/mylib
cd ~/mylib
```

Then you create and edit your source files and headers:

```
cd ~/mylib
vi mylib.h
vi mylib.c
```

To build `mylib` as a static library, do the following:

```
cd ~/mylib
gcc -c mylib.c
ar libmylib.a mylib.o
```

So when you're done, the directory `~/mylib` contains the following:

```
libmylib.a
mylib.c 
mylib.h
mylib.o
```

To use the functions collected in `mylib` in a program, you'd specify the header and library include paths as part of the compile command:

```
gcc -o executable-name command-line-options source-files -I ~/mylib -L ~/mylib -lmylib
```

So, if you `include "mylib.h"` in another program, this will tell the compiler to search for that header in `~/mylib`, and it will tell the linker that the `libmylib.a` library will be found under `~/mylib`.

In a real-world situation you'd handle all of the builds with makefiles instead of building everything by hand.  You'd also probably set it up so that as part of the build process, all the headers that anyone else would need to use your library would be copied to a separate `include` subdirectory, and the library would be written to a separate `lib` subdirectory, so you could distribute your library without exposing your source code.  In that case, the build command above would look more like:

```
gcc -o executable-name command-line-options source-files -I ~/mylib/include -L ~/mylib/lib -lmylib
```

---

<sup>1. This hasn't always been the case; the earliest implementations of C++ used `iostream.h`, `vector.h`, etc.  I'm not sure exactly when that convention changed, but it's been a while.


2. Actually, I'm not sure anymore if this is a `gcc` convention or a `*nix` convention; the two have been joined at the hip for so long it's hard to remember sometimes.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the compiler doesn't know anything about other source files, it only knows about the current [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). It's the job of the [*linker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) to take all translation units and link them together with the libraries to create the executable program, and it's the linker that will resolve all definitions and that notice missing function definitions.

Traditionally, working with C or C++ is a four step process:

1. Edit files
2. Compile source files into object files
3. Link object files and libraries to generate the executable program
4. Run the program.

<sub>The preprocessor is usually built into the compiler, so preprocessing and compiling is only a single step.</sub>

---

As for the "missing" `.h`, none of the C++-only standard library header files have that extension.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Template Library headers, such as < algorithm > include source code for the template functions, which get instantiated at compile time, based on the  template type(s) involved in source code calls to template functions.

A library is a collection of object files in a single library file. The linker normally only includes the object files needed to satisfy the references to functions or data to build the program, not the entire library file. The exception to this is a dynamic link library, since all of that library will be loaded (if not already loaded) at program load time.

The compiler has default locations for headers using < > and using " ". The headers using " ", can include relative or absolute paths. The relative path may vary depending on the tool set.

Answer (score 0):

Re

> **”** How a compiler knows from a header file, that a source file exists somewhere?

Generally, how a compiler locates header files, or if they *are* files, depends on the compiler.

But usually one or more of the following mechanisms are used:

- The compiler knows its own program location, and can look for **include directories** for standard headers, relative to that location. g++ does this.
- The compiler can be configured with paths to include directories in one or more environment variables. E.g. g++ uses `CPATH` (among others), and Visual C++ uses `INCLUDE` (and possibly more).
- The compiler can accept include directory paths as command line options. Typically this is `-I` or with Visual C++, alternatively `/I`.
- The compiler can be configured via a configuration file in a well known location. For example, g++ uses a `specs` file.
- The compiler can accept one or more configuration files as command line options. E.g. Visual C++ accepts so called "response files", and g++ accepts specs files, although with slightly different semantics than the general configuration specs file.

Possibly there are more mechanisms in use, but the above are the most common ones.

---

Re

> **”** But when and how does the compiler include the math functions, if I include math.h?

It doesn't.

The whole of the standard library is linked in regardless of what headers you include. Depending on the quality of the implementation the unused parts of the standard library are then discarded.

When you use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library you will generally have to explicitly link with that library, in addition to including one or more of its headers. The Visual C++ compiler supports `#pragma` directives that can be placed in headers and serve to automatically direct the linker. But this is not standardized, and e.g. g++ does not support that automagic mechanism.

---

Re

> **”** If I create a library, then where to put the .c/.cpp/.h files, and how to include them?

Essentially you have free reins, you can do it any way you want. Which is problematic because users of a C++ library have to deal with different conventions and tools for each library, to the extent of using a different OS to "configure" things. However, nowadays it's popular to employ CMake for libraries with separate compilation, which helps to reduce the DIY problems.

A nice alternative is to create a **header only library**, with all the code in headers. Large parts of Boost are header only. The advantage is that it's very easy to use, no configuration or toolset adaption or whatever, but with currently popular 1950's build technology it can cause longer build times.